# Issue with magento 1.9 bulk configurable product import

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import, csv

I have more than 1700+ configurable products with my csv. I had prepared & Tested the csv import format for magento successfully. It's working great.

The import csv have more than 8500 rows and had tried to import with magento import/export. It's not able to import all the product in single shot. 
Then i had split each 25 products in one csv and uploaded it it's work. After 300 products uploaded now the import process supporting only for 1 or 2 products in single time.

I don't have a idea, how to import more than 1500+ in single shot.

Thanks

Comment: I have same issue, try magmi

Answer (score 1):

I managed import for several project and I was able to import products through the magento default module only once because it had a few dozain products. You will need to use magmi or something of your own to do more.

For magmi, you can find it here https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Answer (score 1):

Use any bulk product import module.
Read CSV file and create multidimensional array to update in one go.

Sample Array structure ...

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'sku' => 'simple1',
        '_type' => 'simple',
        '_attribute_set' => 'Default',
        '_product_websites' => 'base',
        'name' => 'Simple Product 1',
        'description' => 'Default',
        'short_description' => 'Default',
        'price' => 10,
        'weight' => 0,
        'status' => 1,
        'visibility' => 4,
        'tax_class_id' => 2,
        'qty' => 99,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'sku' => 'simple2',
        '_type' => 'simple',
        '_attribute_set' => 'Default',
        '_product_websites' => 'base',
        'name' => 'Simple Product 2',
        'description' => 'Default',
        'short_description' => 'Default',
        'price' => 10,
        'weight' => 0,
        'status' => 1,
        'visibility' => 4,
        'tax_class_id' => 2,
        'qty' => 99,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'sku' => 'grouped',
        '_type' => 'grouped',
        '_attribute_set' => 'Default',
        '_product_websites' => 'base',
        'name' => 'Grouped Product',
        'description' => 'Default',
        'short_description' => 'Default',
        'status' => 1,
        'visibility' => 4,
        'tax_class_id' => 2,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        '_associated_sku' => array('simple1', 'simple2'),
        '_associated_position' => array('1', '2'),
    ),
);

// now update that array collection in one go

try {
    /** @var $import AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import */
    $import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
    $import
        ->setUseNestedArrays(true)
        ->processProductImport($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($import->getErrorMessages());
}
```

[Git Link for AvS_FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport)

[Link for AvS_FastSimpleImport](http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/products.html)